# JavaScript "undefined" value

Tags: javascript, undefined

Im a very newbie to JS. Would anyone please explain how did I got the "undefined" value base on this script below:

```js
const hummus = function(factor) {
  const ingredient = function(amount, unit, name) {
    let ingredientAmount = amount * factor;
    if (ingredientAmount > 1) {
      unit += "s";
    }
    console.log(`${ingredientAmount}, ${unit}, ${name}`);
  };
  ingredient(1, "can", "chickpeas");
  ingredient(0.25, "cup", "tahini");
  ingredient(0.25, "cup", "lemon juice");
  ingredient(1, "clove", "garlic");
  ingredient(2, "tablespoon", "olive oil");
  ingredient(0.5, "teaspoon", "cumin");
};
console.log(hummus(6))
```

**Output result:**

```
6, cans, chickpeas  
1.5, cups, tahini  
1.5, cups, lemon juice  
6, cloves, garlic  
12, tablespoons, olive oil  
3, teaspoons, cumin  
undefined
```

If I change the last code *console.log(hummus(6))* to only *hummus(6)*, the **undefined** value will be omitted from the output result. I just want to know how the **undefined** value generated in this circumstances. I appreciate all your helps.

Comment: the undefined is the result of `console.log(hummus(6))` since `hummus` has no `return` value so it returns `undefined` - just run `hummus(6)` and your undefined will vanish

Comment: Because the `hummus` method does not return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it shows `undefined` is because it is logging the return value from the executed function `hummus`.

Add a return statement at the end of the hummus function, then it should return the value instead of `undefined`.

```js
const hummus = function(factor) {
  // ...

  return "Hello world";
};

console.log(hummus(6))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#description

> To return a value other than the default, a function must have a return statement that specifies the value to return. A function without a return statement will return a default value. In the case of a constructor called with the new keyword, the default value is the value of its this parameter. For all other functions, the default return value is undefined.

JavaScript by default, as comments mentioned, is return `undefined`, you could check it by running `console.log((()=>{})());`

Comment: Thank you for your great explaination. Now I got the idea.